# hola hice un botón de día y noche pero no sé porque se activa cuando presiono cualquier botón

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hice un botón de día y noche pero no sé porque se activa cuando presiono cualquier botón que está en la página y espero que me ayuden en buscar solución

```
  <script>

              const colorSwitch = document.querySelector(&#39;.theme-switch input[type=&quot;checkbox&quot;]&#39;);

        function switchColor(e) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                document.documentElement.setAttribute(&#39;data-theme&#39;, &#39;dark&#39;);
            }
            else {
                document.documentElement.setAttribute(&#39;data-theme&#39;, &#39;light&#39;);
            }
        }
       document.addEventListener(&#39;change&#39;, switchColor, false);
  
</script>
```

lo que esta cambiando

```
        :root{
    --coloruno: $colorP; 
    --colordos: $colorBuscador; 
    --colorFondo: $colorFondo;
    --headingColor: $headingColor; 
    --linkColor: $linkColor;
    --footerColor: $footerColor;
}

[data-theme="dark"]{
    --coloruno: #131313;
    --colordos: #090909;
    --colorFondo: #090909;
    --headingColor: #ffffff;
    --linkColor: #ffffff;
    --footerColor: #131313;
}
```

el boton

```
 <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
            <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
```

Link de la página que estoy trabajando que tiene el error:
https://zonagamerdescarga.blogspot.com/

espero que me ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que vi no es que se activa al presionar cualquier botón... lo que pasa es que cuando lo activas, y aprietas cualquier otro botón, lo que hace es recargar la página y como no estas guardando en ningún lado el cambio pues, vuelve al estado inicial.ç

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

la mejor manera sería guardando el cambio de theme en una cookie. chequea el link

Comment: a ok muchas gracias, pero me podrías dar un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, es que soy nuevo en esto apenas estoy aprendiendo js

Comment: aqui hay algo similar, donde se tiene un boton para cambiar de modo dark a light y viceversa,

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434590/guardar-url-en-cache-usando-localstorage/434717#434717